# Why is Hermione's Patronus not as powerful as her other magic spells?

Tags: harry-potter, patronus-charm, hermione-granger

Hermione's Patronus is an otter, but it is not as powerful as Harry's. Being the best at everything she does, why is it that her magic isn't best at that particular spell? Does it have anything to do with her personality?

Comment: I don't think there's enough to put this as a full answer, but t seems the Patronus spell is a passionate spell, and Hermione approaches everything intellectually, not emotionally.  She may have problems summoning up the passion needed to create a powerful Patronus.

Comment: @Chad - http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Signature_spell - "Expelliarmus is a useful spell, Harry, but the Death Eaters believe it's your signature move and I urge you not to let it become so!" - The reasoning was it was the same thing they saw him do in earlier situations (graveyard scene of GoF IIRC)

Comment: Because they wanted to show harry was better than hermione at at least one thing..

Comment: I agree with @Tango.  Hermoine is not "the best at everything", she has a talent for academics that shines in school (note she's not so good at the physical like brooms, or particularly skillful with people).  That intellectual leaning would mean she could do quite well at advanced magics that required precision, complexity, and knowledge.  However, that doesn't automatically translate into the magics based on emotion and determination...or even raw power.  She can manage the spell by skill, but Harry's strengths are well suited, so he does better.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

The Patronus Charm, according to the Harry Potter series, is a powerful spell.

In *Harry Potter and The Order of the Phoenix*, during the O.W.L. exams, the reader learns many grown wizards and witches have difficulty successfully conjuring a Patronus Charm.

Upon witnessing Harry Potter learn and master that spell by the end of *Harry Potter and The Prisoner of Azkaban*, that is a glimpse ahead into the powerful wizard he will become. People might think power is measured in terms of destruction and mayhem, but true power is that quiet intensity a wizard like Dumbledore displays. Sure, you can blow things up and create fear in others, but there's nothing constructive in that endeavor.

I see Hermione's brand of magic as more tricky and charm laden. Hermione is a wealth of knowledge and information, always in search of more. She masters the small spells quickly, but the Patronus Charm requires you to dig into the mind and heart for happiness while under extreme fear and urgency in most cases. A nuanced wand movement or special technique is not the requirement; raw emotion and energy are. Hermione, when she faltered a little, couldn't have previously imagined being trapped in that situation. She likes to be prepared; but no one can prepare for something not yet experienced.

An interesting note about otters that could be relevant or not: they are family oriented animals. The entire family of them raises their young, and support each other. Hermione is a huge support system to Harry and Ron. Her wealth of information, orderly way of planning ahead, and keenly logical mind carry the trio through so many legs of Harry's journey.

Comment: I like your answer a lot! The only comments I have are minor. I think it's in *Prisoner of Azkaban* that Lupin first tells Harry that many fully-qualified witches and wizards cannot easily produce a Patronus, if at all. I also think that Hermione masters complex magic as a whole. For example, during her fifth year, she applies the Protean Charm to the magic coins the DA uses, which is a N.E.W.T.- level spell. :)

Comment: Reason for downvote?

Comment: I didn't downvote your answer. In fact I'm pretty clear in my comments that I like your answer a lot. I have downvoted, oh, maybe five times since joining SE, and *every single time* I downvote, I leave an explanation as to why. I think it's only the stand-up thing to do. If you received a downvote, it was not from me. :)

Comment: @Slytherincess That comment wasn't for you. :) It was intended for the person who downvoted my answer.

Comment: It was in my in-box -- weird, eh?

Answer (score 18):

Well, first, I think it's because Harry is better than Hermione at Defence Against the Dark Arts in general. Even Hermione admits it:

> *‘Harry, you’re the best in the year at Defence Against the Dark Arts,’ said Hermione.
>
>
>   ‘Me?’ said Harry, now grinning more broadly than ever. ‘No I’m not, you’ve beaten me in every test –’
>
>
>   ‘Actually, I haven’t,’ said Hermione coolly. ‘You beat me in our third year – the only year we both sat the test and had a teacher who actually knew the subject. But I’m not talking about test results, Harry Think what you’ve* done*!’*
>   *Order of the Phoenix* - Page 292 - British Hardcover

I see Hermione as extremely logical, organised, intellectual, and unusually perceptive when it comes to learning. However, I think she struggles with regulating her emotions (as do we all here and there) and she is a teenage girl. She demonstrates her emotional volatility throughout the series through her interactions with and reactions to Ron. She also experiences fear and admits it. The Patronus Charm is contingent upon conjuring happy memories, as everyone has mentioned, and because of her internal rigidity, I think Hermione struggles a bit more with spells and charms that *involve emotion*. We never once see her cast an Unforgivable, IIRC, while Harry and Ron, who are both more overt with their emotions, do. I would imagine that once she actually produces a full corporeal Patronus, that her Patronus has the same defensive capabilities as Harry's does. I suspect, though, that she has a harder time actually conjuring one.

And that's my INFJ opinion :)

Comment: _I would imagine that once she actually produces a full corporeal Patronus, that her Patronus has the same defensive capabilities as Harry's does. I suspect, though, that she has a harder time actually conjuring one._ At least until she has something able to evoke strong emotions in spite of her intellect. By the time of the epilogue in The Deathly Hallows I would wager that Hermione's patronus would be just as good as Harry's, if not better.

Comment: @Xantec -- You may very well be right. I would say, sure, as good as Harry's, but I'd have to think a little longer on whether or not it was *better*. Hermione is a very powerful witch, but no-one in the practical applications of life is the best at everything. Harry's specialty is DADA, so I tend to want to give him the edge. :)

Comment: Sure Harry is good at it on the whole, having specialized for it. But one of the main points of the series is the power of a mother's love, which I think in this case would give Hermione the edge (since she doesn't seem the type to dislike or be dismissive towards her children).

Comment: @Xantec -- I guess I'm not seeing the connection between Hermione's parenting style and the strength of her Patronus. That would imply that somehow witches who do not dislike or dismiss their children would always produce more powerful Patronuses than wizards, because only women can bear children and be mothers. I can't *quite* see the connection. :) Who's to say that if James had been the one to give his life for Harry in the same way Lily had, that Harry wouldn't have had the same protection? I interpret canon to imply that love itself is a theme and is not gender-specific. YMMV, of course.

Comment: Except that James _had_ given his life for Harry, and Lily as well. It didn't do Lily much good, and while I'm no expert I don't recall anyone ever mentioning James' sacrifice when speaking about Harry's protective spell.

Comment: I think it's different. James wasn't the one refusing to step aside in Harry's bedroom and putting himself between Harry and Voldemort; had he been, who knows? There are some terrible mothers out there, and some amazing fathers. I still think the overall theme of the series is love, and that it happened to be a woman who died for Harry does not have any bearing on the Patronus Charm. :)

Comment: I think that is the point, James wasn't given a choice - his lordship only offered Lily a chance to survive (most likely because her childhood sweetheart Sev asked him to).

Comment: @BMWurm -- "His Lordship" is a rather ... grand ... title for Voldemort. Is it in the books?

Comment: Not that I can remember a quote, he styled himself after all, though I think it was used mockingly once...

Answer (score 11):

I don't think there's a fully canonical answer. However some possibilities are:

- It's not Hermione's Patronus that's unusually un-powerful (for her age), it's Harry's that is - possibly due to some inherited abilities, possibly to personality (his Patronus power rivals or exceeds most adult wizards, whereas - absent weird entanglements with Voldemort - he is usually NOT that good/successful compared to experienced powereful wizards - look at him trying to duel with Snape at the end of HP6 for an example).
- Related - Hermione's magic is not innately **powerful** - it's merely her skills are great. Expecto Patronus is less of a technical skill spell and more of a raw energy/emotional one.
- Sort of related to the last one - just like it requires a certain mindset to successfully cast Cruciatus, perhaps the same is true of Patronus. I don't have the excact quote but it's stated that you need unusually positive memory. Hermione, has happy memories, but she possibly doesn't have the required contrast between her generally not-unhappy life and her happiest memories that Harry has, or her emotional intensity may be on INTJ-typical lower level in general *(source: I'm basically half-Hermione :)*.

Comment: i agree with your last point, Hermione lived a happy life, but she probably doesnt have moments like harry in which the happiness is explosive. getting something nice for your birthday, getting into hogwarts, could be very similar for hermione, but for someone like harry with mostly sad/bad/neurtral memories, something like this isuch a burst of happiness and joy it can help produce a much stronger patronus.

Answer (score 5):

Hermione didn't have the same driving need to perfect her Patronus, because the Dementors didn't affect her as strongly. It wasn't the thing she feared the most against the Boggart. She wasn't likely to see a Patronus Charm on a test either.

Harry had a lot of motivation to develop a powerful Patronus. Both in terms of learning to protect himself and defending those he cared about.

Answer (score 5):

Hermione's Patronus only seems weak when compared to Harry's. And Harry had more practice.

Harry learned the Patronus charm back in "Prisoner of Azkaban", and it took a long time before he was able to cast it at all, longer before he became proficient at it. But he kept practicing until he was satisfied that he could handle the dementors.

Hermione simply never got that amount of practice. The Patronus charm was never part of their coursework, and it was never mentioned as being in any volume of "The Standard Book of Spells" so she couldn't learn it just by reading ahead. I don't think Hermione had ever even tried casting a Patronus prior to the D.A., by which time Harry already had a huge head start.

I think I remember Hermione mentioning in "Deathly Hallows" that she had been practicing the talking-Patronus trick, but that's different from practicing the Patronus in the face of dementors (or boggarts), like Harry did.