# Which Myers-Briggs personality is Hermione?

Tags: harry-potter, psychology

In one of my answers ( [Why is Hermione's Patronus not as powerful as her other magic spells?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/8959/why-is-hermiones-patronus-not-as-powerful-as-her-other-magic-spells/8964#8964) ) I stated that Hermione is [INTJ](http://typelogic.com/intj.html) (Introverted iNtuitive Thinking Judging) on a [Myers-Briggs Type Indicator personality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Myers-Briggs_Type_Indicator) scale.

But I'm not quite certain if that's the case as I don't recall the exact test parameters - my statement was based on seeing a lot of my own (INTJ) personality in her.

Is there any evidence (e.g. either JKR statement, or FAQ, or someone actually plugging known details of Hermione's personality into Meyers-Briggs) to show whether she's INTJ or some other flavor?

Comment: Unless you can get the [Word of God](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/WordOfGod), it seems like this is going to be a subjective discussion of her typical behaviors with regardings to the Meyers-Briggs test.

Comment: @IanPugsley - M-B is fairly objective IIRC. The "I" parrt is 100% certain. And I wouldn't put it past Her Who Must Not Be Named to pull a word of god out of some obscure chat log :)

Comment: I can't say that I see this kind of questions as particularly good for the site: rather like *Hidden features* on Stack Overflow you invite one for every character every written.

Comment: @dmckee - very few characters have personality detailed enough to have this be answerable. Also, are we THAT drowning in questions that we need to throttle>?

Comment: @DVK: Maybe few characters in movies or really popular stuff have that much character, but SF&F is a *big* world. Nor is it about the number of questions we have *now*. It's about what the site looks like years from now. Bikeshed questions aren't just fun, they also effect how the site looks to newcomers. The time to not go there is now.

Comment: @Ian - Googling for "hermione meyers-briggs" brings VERY VERY detailed (some pretty psych-heavy scholarly) discussions. Consensus seems to be ISNJ, with some people arguing for less common types). So it's definitely answerable objectively if someone familiar with details of MBTI scans through those discussions - they are a wee bit over my head in technical details.

Comment: While MBTI can be considered subjective, unless you have a number of psychologists or other mental health professionals discussing this, any answers are purely speculation and totally subjective.  Without "Word of God," even with links, any answers will either be speculation or something that's "general reference" because it was easily Googled.

Comment: @Tango - as noted in earlier comment, I've seen what seemed to be discussions between professionals on the topic.

Comment: Yes, but even then, it's supposition.  I used to work in treatment and, while professionals may say they think that's the case, none that I worked with would ever be willing to say they could be 100% sure without having the person in question take the test.  But on the other hand, while some professionals I worked with did give weight to MBTI, many didn't give it but so much credence - some considered it simplistic and others considered it pop psych.  So there's not even a consensus in the field on the test itself, much less, what any person would score on it.

Comment: @DVK professional mental health workers cannot make clinical findings of individuals based upon indirect evidence, despite what you may see on shows such as "Dr. Phil". Any discussion done by professionals is still therefore subjective, as objective professional analysis would require direct interviewing of fictional characters.

Comment: @DVK - Beofett is right about mental health/psychological professionals or social workers being unable to make clinical findings ***solely*** by proxy. Supplemental info (i.e. not directly from the person being assessed) is certainly valuable, but is considered as only one facet of the whole picture that is clinical findings. Yes, supplemental and anecdotal information is given consideration, but only within the context of the direct interview and assessment with an individual.  :)

Comment: @Beofett - what's "Dr Phil"?

Comment: @DVK (Disclaimer: this is my personal opinion of Dr. Phil): [Dr. Phil](http://drphil.com/shows/page/bio/) is a television personality popular in the US (much to our shame!) who routinely violates professional ethics to sensationalize and capitalize upon people's mental health issues under the flimsy premise of "helping people" (which, to him, apparently translates as "ratings").

Answer (score 7, accepted):

TV Tropes has quite a collection of Myer's Briggs descriptions for [fictional characters](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/JustForFun/ExamplesOfMyersBriggsPersonalitiesInStories?from=Main.ExamplesOfMyersBriggsPersonalitiesInStories) and their lists match quite a few I have seen over the years.

Hermione Granger is listed there as an [ISTJ](http://www.personalitypage.com/ISTJ.html). Introverted, Sensing, Thinking, Judging. ISTJs are orderly, dependable, practical and dutiful above all. They prefer working with facts and can be conservative in their loyalty to traditions.

From the [Personality Profiler](http://www.personalitypage.com/ISTJ.html):

> As an ISTJ, your primary mode of living is focused internally, where you take things in via your five senses in a literal, concrete fashion. Your secondary mode is external, where you deal with things rationally and logically.
>
> ISTJs are quiet and reserved individuals who are interested in
>   security and peaceful living. They have a strongly-felt internal sense
>   of duty, which lends them a serious air and the motivation to follow
>   through on tasks. Organized and methodical in their approach, they can
>   generally succeed at any task which they undertake.
>
> ISTJs are very loyal, faithful, and dependable. They place great
>   importance on honesty and integrity. They are "good citizens" who can
>   be depended on to do the right thing for their families and
>   communities. While they generally take things very seriously, they
>   also usually have an offbeat sense of humor and can be a lot of fun -
>   especially at family or work-related gatherings.
>
> ISTJs tend to believe in laws and traditions, and expect the same from
>   others. They're not comfortable with breaking laws or going against
>   the rules. If they are able to see a good reason for stepping outside
>   of the established mode of doing things, the ISTJ will support that
>   effort. However, ISTJs more often tend to believe that things should
>   be done according to procedures and plans. If an ISTJ has not
>   developed their Intuitive side sufficiently, they may become overly
>   obsessed with structure, and insist on doing everything "by the book".
>
> The ISTJ is extremely dependable on following through with things
>   which he or she has promised. For this reason, they sometimes get more
>   and more work piled on them. Because the ISTJ has such a strong sense
>   of duty, they may have a difficult time saying "no" when they are
>   given more work than they can reasonably handle. For this reason, the
>   ISTJ often works long hours, and may be unwittingly taken advantage
>   of.
>
> The ISTJ will work for long periods of time and put tremendous amounts
>   of energy into doing any task which they see as important to
>   fulfilling a goal. However, they will resist putting energy into
>   things which don't make sense to them, or for which they can't see a
>   practical application. They prefer to work alone, but work well in
>   teams when the situation demands it. They like to be accountable for
>   their actions, and enjoy being in positions of authority. The ISTJ has
>   little use for theory or abstract thinking, unless the practical
>   application is clear.
>
> ISTJs have tremendous respect for facts. They hold a tremendous store
>   of facts within themselves, which they have gathered through their
>   Sensing preference. They may have difficulty understanding a theory or
>   idea which is different from their own perspective. However, if they
>   are shown the importance or relevance of the idea to someone who they
>   respect or care about, the idea becomes a fact, which the ISTJ will
>   internalize and support. Once the ISTJ supports a cause or idea, he or
>   she will stop at no lengths to ensure that they are doing their duty
>   of giving support where support is needed.
>
> The ISTJ is not naturally in tune with their own feelings and the
>   feelings of others. They may have difficulty picking up on emotional
>   needs immediately, as they are presented. Being perfectionists
>   themselves, they have a tendency to take other people's efforts for
>   granted, like they take their own efforts for granted. They need to
>   remember to pat people on the back once in a while.
>
> ISTJs are likely to be uncomfortable expressing affection and emotion
>   to others. However, their strong sense of duty and the ability to see
>   what needs to be done in any situation usually allows them to overcome
>   their natural reservations, and they are usually quite supporting and
>   caring individuals with the people that they love. Once the ISTJ
>   realizes the emotional needs of those who are close to them, they put
>   forth effort to meet those needs.

- Dedicated, forthright, strong sense of internal purpose and duty describe Hermione perfectly.
- Hermione is eminently logical and the brains of Team Potter. They rely on her to remember the important things and she is often overlooked when Team Potter's contributions are considered.
- Hermione has show she is dedicated to the magical traditions, makes
  amazing efforts to master her craft, so much so, she would use
  temporal magicks to get more time to study and learn.
- Her perfectionist nature is shown by her absolute necessity to have a
  spell for every occasion. Her loyalty to her friends is
  unquestionable and unflagging.
- Her emotional reservation displayed with her inability to summon the
  Patronus effectively.

This would be an accurate description of Ms. Granger behaviors. While this is not canon, I can certainly see how Hermione Granger fits this Myer's Briggs profile and while we cannot know what J.K. Rowlings might think of the classification, it certainly describes the character Hermione Granger quite well.

Comment: I woudn't necessarily consider TVTropes as authoritative without detailed explanations of WHY it's INSJ (as you provided).

Comment: DVK said almost exactly what I was going to say.